# ST2 navigation between views

Tags: controller, navigation, sencha-touch-2

I´m new to Sencha Touch 2 and have some question regarding the navigation between views. What is the best way to navigate between different views? I tried using the provided NavigationView class but it doesn´t offer the whole functionality I want.

Currently I´m using a simple `Ext.Container` as a `Viewport` for my app. I declared `refs`for the views and when I change to a new view in my `controller` I currently do it like this:

```
var oldView = this.getOldView();
Ext.destroy(oldView);

var newView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView');
Ext.Viewport.add(newView);
```

But I´m not sure if this is the right approach and couldn´t find proper documenation. Currently it seems to me that the `controller` loses track of the `refs` when I manually destroy the views. So what what is the best way to navigate back and forward between views (similiar to NavigationView´s `push()` and `pop()`)? Do I have to destroy the old view and add a new view? Or do I just hide the old view and add the new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize your views as free as you want, **Ext.NavigationView** is NOT recommended. Use basic types instead, such as: Ext.Container (recommended), Ext.Panel, and so on.

**refs** still works each time you destroy or add your views again, provided that **your component is available**.

But as a newbie, a simple approach (but not optimal for performance) I could suggest you is create all your needed components, and simply activate / deactivate them when needed.

If you want to activate a view, first, you must locate that view's parent. For eg, you have a **Ext.Container** which has three panels in it. Then if you want to activate second panel of that container, use `setActiveItem(yourContainerRef, 1)` (without animation) or `animateActiveItem(yourContainerRef, 1, {type: 'slide'})`